# How to retrieve lastly added events in android calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

According to my requirements i should save the events in android calendar like event name, starDate and endDate etc and retrieve lastly saved events, Now everything goes well, instead of fetching last event values i'm getting first event, can anybody tell the logic for this issue please.

Here's my code

```
 private void addEvent2() {
    Intent l_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    l_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    //l_intent.putExtra("calendar_id", m_selectedCalendarId);  //this doesn't work

    l_intent.putExtra("title", "roman10 calendar tutorial test");
    l_intent.putExtra("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
    l_intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "@home");
    l_intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
    l_intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
    l_intent.putExtra("allDay", 0);
    //status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
    l_intent.putExtra("eventStatus", 1);
    //0~ default; 1~ confidential; 2~ private; 3~ public
    l_intent.putExtra("visibility", 3);
    //0~ opaque, no timing conflict is allowed; 1~ transparency, allow overlap of scheduling
    l_intent.putExtra("transparency", 0);
    //0~ false; 1~ true
    l_intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
    try {
        startActivity(l_intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no compatible calendar is found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Retrieving code

```
private void getLastEvent() {
    Uri l_eventUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }
    String[] l_projection = new String[]{"title", "dtstart", "dtend"};
    Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, "calendar_id=" + m_selectedCalendarId, null, "dtstart DESC, dtend DESC");
    //Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, null, null, null);
    if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int l_cnt = 0;
        String l_title;
        String l_begin;
        String l_end;
        StringBuilder l_displayText = new StringBuilder();
        int l_colTitle = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
        int l_colBegin = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
        int l_colEnd = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
        do {
            l_title = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colTitle);
            l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
            l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));
            l_displayText.append(l_title + "\n" + l_begin + "\n" + l_end + "\n----------------\n");
            ++l_cnt;
        } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext() && l_cnt < 1);
        m_text_event.setText(l_displayText.toString());
                }
    l_managedCursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> retrieve lastly saved events

As long as you don't save the date where you add the event you can't get last added events.

---

Looking in [Calendar.Contract.Events API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html) I can't find any field to insert this kind of extra data, so you have 2 sol.lutions:

- Create a `SharedPreferences` or `DataBase` to store basic data to find a calendar event **PLUS** adding date, then make search in this Preferences or DataBase and retrieve information from calendar according to it.
- **EASIER, BUT NOT RECOMMENDED**
  Add in some `String` field like `DESCRIPTION` or `ORGANIZER` the `Timestamp` or `Date` of addition of the event, then when searching just get this part of the event and sort to get last added.